# software center and ppa not working

Tags: apt, software-center, package-management

I am new to Ubuntu, just today I was trying to download a program with a ppa, crebs, and it did not work; not only that, the software center doesn't work either, and I can't get it from the internet to reinstall.

Here's the error message that I get in the terminal:

```
software-center

2014-07-17 14:56:40,835 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'

2014-07-17 14:56:41,230 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file

2014-07-17 14:56:41,233 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'

2014-07-17 14:56:41,238 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'

2014-07-17 14:56:41,238 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration

2014-07-17 14:56:41,283 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()

2014-07-17 14:56:41,712 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - error creating bsddb: '(22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')' (corrupted?)

2014-07-17 14:56:41,712 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - ERROR - trying to repair DB failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 358, in _save_review_stats_cache_blocking
self._dump_bsddbm_for_unity(outfile, outdir)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 377, in _dump_bsddbm_for_unity
0600)

DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:535: Warning: Source ID 68 was not found when attempting to remove it
return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 261, in open
self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 107, in __init__
self.open(progress)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 151, in open
self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)

SystemError: E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
2014-07-17 14:56:43,162 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
if (not pkgname in self.cache and
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
return self._cache.__contains__(k)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 183, in <module>
app.run(args)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1378, in run
self.show_available_packages(args)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1316, in show_available_packages
self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 150, in set_active_view

view_widget.init_view()
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 227, in init_view
self.cache, self.db, self.icons, self.apps_filter)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 80, in __init__
self.build()
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 326, in build
self._build_homepage_view()
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 121, in _build_homepage_view
self._append_whats_new()
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 255, in _append_whats_new
whats_new_cat = self._update_whats_new_content()
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 240, in _update_whats_new_content
docs = whats_new_cat.get_documents(self.db)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 131, in 

get_documents
nonblocking_load=False)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 330, in set_query
self._blocking_perform_search()  

File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 225, in _blocking_perform_search
matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
if (not pkgname in self.cache and
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

Any idea, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `apt-get` to install something. My first recommendation is to install Synaptic (`sudo apt-get install synaptic`) and just use Synaptic instead of Ubuntu Software Center (USC). You can do **anything** USC can do with Synaptic. **You don't have to use Terminal anymore if you have Synaptic**. You can configure your PPA in Synaptic plus so many features USC doesn't have yet, such as:

- Proxy auth settings.
- KB/s information when downloading
- Create download script for offline installation.
- and many more.

[image]